# Root level domain google clouddns

Tags: google-cloud-dns

How do I make root level domain (http://getdor.com) redirect to http://www.getdor.com/? My domain is managed by Google Cloud DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try CNAME'ng as explained below

getdor.com A 11.22.33.44
www.getdor.com CNAME getdor.com

Comment: I can't use an A record, as I have to point it at c.storage.google.com

Comment: could you elaborate what zones & records u r trying to set. You could mask your actual domain name with example.com types

Comment: I am trying to point both www.getdor.com and getdor.com at c.storage.googleapis.com, so that they can both host the site. When I try to CNAME getdor.com it fails, and states "Error code "cnameResourceRecordSetConflict" : The resource record set 'entity.change.additions[0]' is invalid because the DNS name 'getdor.com.' may have either one CNAME resource record set or resource record sets of other types, but not both."

Comment: On namecheap or aws, I would normally use an ALIAS record, to ALIAS getdor.com to www.getdor.com

Comment: i`m looking for the same information, did you manage to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing
www.getdor.com CNAME http://getdor.com.
http://getdor.com CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com.

this could help ur resolution path